# jQuery mobile: degrade gracefully in non-supported browsers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-support

I'm developing a site in jQuery mobile (jQM). It's great, but one thing is troubling me.

jQM [is not supported in all mobile browsers](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) (notably BlackBerry 5). The site looks gorgeous in the Android browser: on Opera Mini on Android, it's actually broken :(

I've developed the site using progressive enhancement, naturally. So it works without jQM - if I can tell the browser not to use it!

Question: for platforms like Opera Mini on Android, is there a way I can check for jQM support, and totally unapply jQM as appropriate?

- If jQM is supported in this browser, use it.
- If it isn't, don't load the jQM javascript, don't load the jQM stylesheets, and use the basic JavaScript site.

I know about the `gradeA()` property, but you presumably have to load jQM to use it:

```
$.mobile.gradeA()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile tests browser features itself.

You should customize the code to make it resign from doing its enhancements.
Try here if you're interested: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.support.js

Also: If it decides to work - it probably should. Try fixing the problems instead of trying to get jQuery Mobile to degrade

[edit]

Ok. let me explain. JQM, following to the idea of progressive enhancement, tests browser capabilities and kicks in with its widgets and stuff when the browser passes tests. This is why I say it should work if it tries.

If it tries to enhance and fails - it's a bug/missing support on the JQM side and in an ideal world you should expect it to be fixed. Reality suggests you can't expect it, but you can hope for it ;) It's not a release yet.

What I ment with "Try fixing..." is that you should download the JQM repository, add a line or two to the support tests and make them detect the feature that causes JQM to fail in that particular case. Then run `make` and you have a brand new JMQ working for you.

After that you can suggest your change to the core team and they'll improve on it.

[edit]

**This is actually what you really wanted:**

A nice way to get your support-sniffing code in.

You can implement your own `gradeA` function that would return 
`$.support.mediaquery&&yourcondition`

See: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html

This can prevent JQM from working with browsers you don't want.

Comment: "If it decides to work - it probably should" <-- not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: I'm interested in this reply, but I'm afraid I can't work out what you mean. It's not a problem with my code per se - the jQuery Mobile demos themselves don't work in e.g. Opera Mini 6 on Android.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [jquery support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) object? There are [new properties](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/New-%24.support-properties) for mobile. From docs, `gradeA` is a shortcut for `$.support.mediaquery`.

Comment: Ah, so load jQuery first, and then use `.gradeA` to load jQM conditionally? Cunning! That does assume all browsers support jQuery though...

Comment: @simon, yes that's what I am suggesting. I believe that jquery would be supported on modern mobile browsers that supports java-script. Yes, it is possible that some part of jquery API may not be supported but all core functions such as browser detection, events, selectors should work!